# Adding directory to PYTHONPATH causes my home directory to be added as well

Tags: bash, python

I tried adding the directory `/home/myname/bin` to my PYTHONPATH by inserting the following into my `.bashrc`:

```
if [ -d ~/bin ]; then
    export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/myname/bin
fi
```

Unfortunately this seems to add my home directory to Python's search path, as seen by running the following commands in Python:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path

['', '/home/myname', '/home/myname/bin', '/usr/lib/python3.4', '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

Note that `echo $PYTHONPATH` just returns `:/home/myname/bin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are including the existing value of `PYTHONPATH`. That variable, however, is not set, so it evaluates to the empty string. For some reason, that seems to make `python` include your `$HOME` dir. Presumably, that is the default directory:

```
$ python -c 'import sys; print sys.path'
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2']
```

However, if I set `PYTHONPATH` to the empty string, my `$HOME` is included:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=""; python -c 'import sys; print sys.path'
['', '/home/terdon', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2']
```

So, when you include the current value of `PYTHONPATH` when setting it, that's the behavior you get:

```
$ PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:$HOME/bin" python -c 'import sys; print sys.path'
['', '/home/terdon', '/home/terdon/bin', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2']
```

The correct way to set it is by only giving it the directories you want to add:

```
$ PYTHONPATH="$HOME/bin" python -c 'import sys; print sys.path'
['', '/home/terdon/bin', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2']
```

Or, to be on the safe side in case it ever is defined, check whether it is empty and act accordingly:

```
if [ -d ~/bin ]; then
    [ -z "$PYTHONPATH" ] && 
        export PYTHONPATH="/home/myname/bin" ||
        export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/home/myname/bin"
fi
```